# python fucntion to convert SQL queries from sqlite syntax to oracle with my internal specifics

Tags: python-3.x, oracle, sqlite

I want to use python to convert SQL queries from sqlite syntax to oracle with my internal specifics. The function will only handle select statements. The function should take a string as input and return a string as well.

The logic of processing a string in the function is as follows:

1. if the string contains the word LIMIT, it is necessary to analyze what came before it. If there is a where clause in the query, then we need to add and ROWNUM =. If there was no where clause in the query, it must be created according to the rule of the order of sql clauses :
   SELECT
   FROM
   JOIN
   WHERE
   GROUP BY
   HAVING
   ORDER BY
   LIMIT

It should be taken into account that some clauses may not exist - GROUP BY, HAVING, ORDER BY and JOIN. It is necessary to dynamically determine where exactly WHERE clause should be inserted in case of its absence.

Example:
a) 'SELECT T2.bad_alias FROM zip_data AS T1 INNER JOIN avoid AS T2 ON T1.zip_code = T2.zip_code WHERE T1.avg_house_value = ( SELECT MAX(avg_house_value) FROM zip_data ) LIMIT 1' -> 'SELECT T2. bad_alias FROM zip_data AS T1 INNER JOIN avoid AS T2 ON T1.zip_code = T2.zip_code WHERE T1.avg_house_value = ( SELECT MAX(avg_house_value) FROM zip_data ) AND ROWNUM = 1'
b) 'SELECT t.state, T1.first_name, T1.last_name FROM zip_data AS T INNER JOIN congress AS T1 ON t.state = T1.abbreviation GROUP BY t.state ORDER BY SUM(t.asian_population) DESC LIMIT 3' -> 'SELECT t.state, T1.first_name, T1.last_name FROM zip_data AS T INNER JOIN congress AS T1 ON t.state = T1.abbreviation WHERE ROWNUM = 1 GROUP BY t.state ORDER BY SUM(t.asian_population) DESC'

2. aliases to tables in SELECT and JOIN clauses should not contain AS, they should be removed

Example:  'SELECT T2.bad_alias FROM zip_data AS T1 INNER JOIN avoid AS T2 ON T1.zip_code = T2.zip_code WHERE T1.avg_house_value = ( SELECT MAX(avg_house_value) FROM zip_data ) AND ROWNUM = 1' -> 'SELECT T2. bad_alias FROM zip_data T1 INNER JOIN avoid T2 ON T1.zip_code = T2.zip_code WHERE T1.avg_house_value = ( SELECT MAX(avg_house_value) FROM zip_data ) AND ROWNUM = 1''

3. column names that are selected from source tables (not from CTE) must be enclosed in double quotation marks.

Example: 'SELECT T2.bad_alias FROM zip_data T1 INNER JOIN avoid T2 ON T1.zip_code = T2.zip_code WHERE T1.avg_house_value = ( SELECT MAX(avg_house_value) FROM zip_data ) AND ROWNUM = 1' -> 'SELECT T2. 'bad_alias' FROM zip_data T1 INNER JOIN avoid T2 ON T1.'zip_code' = T2.'zip_code' WHERE T1.'avg_house_value' = ( SELECT MAX('avg_house_value') FROM zip_data ) AND ROWNUM = 1'

I've tried several variations, but to no avail. I am thinking of using a tree to know where to insert the where clause from point 1, but so far no luck either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Assuming that you are using Oracle 12 or later and your queries do not include `LIMIT` as column names or within literals then just globally replace the regular expression `\bLIMIT\s+(\d+)\b` with `FETCH FIRST \1 ROWS ONLY`.
2. You can also globally remove `\bAS\s+` since, in Oracle, the `AS` keyword before a table or view identifier is forbidden and before column identifiers it is optional so you can just remove it everywhere. (Again, assuming that it is not part of a literal.)
3. > column names that are selected from source tables (not from CTE) must be enclosed in double quotation marks.

   If you are following best-practice then do **NOT** do this. Just leave all the column names unquoted (both in your queries and in the DDL statements used to create the tables and views).

In python, that would be:

```python
import re

queries = (
    'SELECT T2.bad_alias FROM zip_data AS T1 INNER JOIN avoid AS T2 ON T1.zip_code = T2.zip_code WHERE T1.avg_house_value = ( SELECT MAX(avg_house_value) FROM zip_data ) LIMIT 1',
    'SELECT t.state, T1.first_name, T1.last_name FROM zip_data AS T INNER JOIN congress AS T1 ON t.state = T1.abbreviation GROUP BY t.state ORDER BY SUM(t.asian_population) DESC LIMIT 3',
)

for query in queries:
    updated_query = re.sub(r"\bLIMIT\s+(\d+)\b", r"FETCH FIRST \1 ROWS ONLY", query)
    updated_query = re.sub(r"\bAS\s+", r"", updated_query)
    print(updated_query)
```

Which outputs:

```
SELECT T2.bad_alias FROM zip_data T1 INNER JOIN avoid T2 ON T1.zip_code = T2.zip_code WHERE T1.avg_house_value = ( SELECT MAX(avg_house_value) FROM zip_data ) FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY
SELECT t.state, T1.first_name, T1.last_name FROM zip_data T INNER JOIN congress T1 ON t.state = T1.abbreviation GROUP BY t.state ORDER BY SUM(t.asian_population) DESC FETCH FIRST 3 ROWS ONLY
```

---

If you are using Oracle 11 or earlier then trying to handle edge cases like `SELECT * FROM a WHERE a.x IN (SELECT b.x FROM b WHERE b.y = a.y ORDER BY b.x DESC LIMIT 1)` is going to cause you significant issues trying to automate the process and you are probably going to want to convert the queries by hand.

If your queries are simpler than that then you probably still need to parse the SQL grammar to an abstract syntax tree and then modify the output by replacing:

```sql
SELECT ...
FROM ...
[WHERE ...]
[GROUP BY ...]
[HAVING ...]
[ORDER BY ...]
LIMIT n
```

With:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT ...
  FROM ...
  [WHERE ...]
  [GROUP BY ...]
  [HAVING ...]
  [ORDER BY ...]
)
WHERE ROWNUM <= n
```

Which may be difficult with string functions if the `LIMIT` query is nested in a sub-query.

Comment: fanks, that helped me a lot!